# Find/Access file on CDROM drive using C#

Tags: .net, file-copying, cd-rom

I am trying to **locate a file on CD-ROM drive to copy to hard drive** using C# console application.

I am able to find drive letter and drive name. But I am not sure how to find or locate file so that I can perform copy operation from CD-ROM drive to hard drive.

While trying to achieve my above purpose, I have tried below code so far.

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in collection)
{
   if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom)
   {
      if (drive.IsReady)
      {
         try
         {
            string filePath = drive.RootDirectory.ToString();
            string name = drive.Name;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            path = filePath + "\\" + fileName;

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
               File.Copy(path, @"C:\Users\newfolder");
            }

            MessageBox.Show("File is copied. Please run BC 360 agai");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("There is some problem with copying file: \n" + ex.Message);
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would enumerate all directories and the files they contain and then compare the names until you find what you want.

See here for [How to: Enumerate Directories and Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370(v=vs.110).ASPx)

However what I don't understand is, if you need to locate the file you have to already know what the name of the file is, right? So you are missing the relative path of the file on the CD-ROM?

Comment: Thanks Frank, This enumeration helped. Can you extend your help a little bit more. To satisfy my copy operation, my exe is first getting installed in machine. when next time if I again trying to copy a file with same exe, the machine does not allow me. Is there anyway I can uninstall the application as soon as my copy operation is completed?

Comment: Well, that depends on what installation tool you are using e.g. Click Once, Installshield, WIX and so on... I would ask a different question for that since that has nothing to do with file enumeration. Plus your requirement makes not really sense: you install a software that copies a  file from a CD-ROM of which you don't know where exactly it is on the CD-ROM and then removes itself again?

Comment: Purpose of my application to provide an executable CD along with *.jar file in it. My vendor is going to use it. who is not so tech savvy. I am using Click Once tool which installs the application on my vendor's machine. But if I provide another jar file next time with the executable it won't run as the application is already installed. Apologies as I didn't clear the scenario earlier.